# XML get busted in arabic language

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, localization, android-relativelayout

I have this xml hierarchy and in case of English it working absolutely fine. But when i change language to Arabic then its getting disturbed. I am using MarginStart and MarginEnd. But still its not working fine in case of Arabic.

XML File

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/daily_intake"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/below_line"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/your_daily_intake_text"
                android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/daily_intake"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selector_text_111"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/proteins_bar_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDailyProts"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/selector_text_111"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.proteins}"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />


                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selector_value_11"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/carbohydrates_bar_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDailyCarbs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/selector_value_11"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.carbohydrates}"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selector_value_113"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/calories_bar_text"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtDailyCals"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/selector_value_113"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.calories}"
                        android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />


                </RelativeLayout>


            </RelativeLayout>
```

[image: English output]

[image: Arabic Output]

Please help if i am missing something in case of localization. I am doing localization in all over the app but getting problem here. Cannot figure out what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the changed XML.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/daily_intake"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_text_111"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/proteins_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyProts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.proteins}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_value_11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/carbohydrates_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyCarbs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.carbohydrates}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_value_113"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/calories_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyCals"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.calories}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /Replace your code with this/

 Note : Always remember to use android:layout_marginLeft with
 android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd with 
 android:layout_marginRight

 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/daily_intake"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/below_line"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/your_daily_intake_text"
            android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/daily_intake"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_text_111"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/proteins_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyProts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/selector_text_111"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.proteins}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_value_11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/carbohydrates_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyCarbs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/selector_value_11"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.carbohydrates}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/selector_value_113"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/calories_bar_text"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDailyCals"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/selector_value_113"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:text="@={bmiSummaryFragmentViewModel.calories}"
                    android:textColor="@color/default_text_color" />


            </RelativeLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry yash786, that was not the solution. Android discourage this by giving a warning to use android:layout_marginLeft with
 android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd with 
 android:layout_marginRight.

Comment: But appreciate your answer. Thanks alot. :)